# LTE PC5 Subframe Structure

Tags: standard, lte

LTE provides sidelink communication via the PC5 interface.

According to the "secondary literature" [1],[2],[3], the PC5 subframe is structured as follows:

- Symbol 0,1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12: PSCCH, PSSCH (Primary Sidelink Control /
  Shared Channel
- Symbol 2, 5, 8, 11: DMRS (Demodulation Reference Signal)
- Symbol 13: Guard for TX/RX Turnaround

Unfortunately, I cannot find the primary source for this subframe structure in the ETSI Technical Standards (e.g. ETSI TS 136 211 [4]). Could somebody please point me into the right direction?

Many thanks in advance,

EMC

[1] ETSI TR 137 985 V16.0.0 (2020-07), p. 10
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/137900_137999/137985/16.00.00_60/tr_137985v160000p.pdf

[2] ETSI TR 121 914 V14.0.0 (2018-06), p. 28
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/121900_121999/121914/14.00.00_60/tr_121914v140000p.pdf

[3] Shashank Kumar Gupta, Jamil Yusuf Khan and Duy Trong Ngo: An LTE-Direct-Based Communication System for Safety Services in Vehicular Networks, Figure 5
https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/72121

[4] LTE; Evolved Universal Terrestrial Radio Access (E-UTRA); Physical channels and modulation (3GPP TS 36.211 version 15.14.0 Release 15)
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/121900_121999/121914/14.00.00_60/tr_121914v140000p.pdf